# sonata Page : I didn't find a block Type when I want to create a new page

Tags: symfony, sonata

I didn't find a block types when I want to create a new block from backend with sonata admin. I want to have a "StringBlock" like the demo.

Any solution or configuration ?

Thanks.

Comment: At this point, it is highly unclear what you are trying to ask. I would recommend you to go and read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a working example and somebody can definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed. It's a configuration problem. I added this line to config.yml:

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [sonata_page_bundle]
```